# unable to make content take up the entire grid-cell space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following top level `css grid`. It has 2 rows and 2 columns. In 1st row, I have put a `<p>` which occupies the entire row. In 2nd row, I have placed 2 components, 1 in each column

```
.homepage-component-css-grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  
  height:100%; 
}


p { /*1 row, 2 columns*/
  font: 300 1.5em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
app-practice-component{ /*2nd row, 1st column*/
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:end;

}

app-create-component{/*2nd row, 2nd column*/
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:start;

}
```

`app-create-component` and `app-practice-components` are themselves css grids of 4 rows, 1 column. I am placing 1 `<p>` each in the 1st 3 rows and 1 `<button>` in the 4th row

```
.css-grid-container__create-div{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}



.css-grid-item__create-para1-div{
  margin-left:40px;
  margin-top:30px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.css-grid-item__create-para2-div{
  margin-left:40px;
  margin-top:30px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.css-grid-item__create-para3-div{
  margin-left:40px;
  margin-top:30px;
  grid-column: 1  / -1;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.css-grid-item__create-button-div{
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:center;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}
```

The page looks the following:

[image]

As its visible, the `app-create-component` and `app-practice-components` are not taking up the entire space of the cell. Their size seem to be dependent on the size of the content in them. How could I make them take up say 90% of the available size in the grid cell they are in. I tried using `height:90%` and `width:90%` but that didn't work

Comment: We can't debug an image and some CSS fragments, we need a [mcve]

Comment: In `.homepage-component-css-grid-container`, instead of `height: 100%`, try `height: 100vh`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276